# Display Spring-Boot Banner with Root-Logger WARN

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, logback

Under development and test environment the ROOT logger level is DEBUG or INFO. The spring-boot banner is displayed at application startup:

```
2017-03-23 14:31:00,322 [INFO ]                 - 
 :: Spring Boot ::         (v1.5.2.RELEASE)
 :: Application ::         AcMe (v1.0-SNAPSHOT)
 :: Build ::               2017-03-23 09:53
```

But when running in a production environment the my ROOT logger level is normally WARN. This causes the banner not to be printed out.

How to configure logback so that the banner will be displayed also in production?

My guess was to add another logger, but the following (and alike configuration) did not work:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
```

Here my configuration

application.properties:

```
  spring.main.banner-mode=log
```

application-devel.properties:

```
  logging.config=classpath:logging-spring-devel.xml
```

application-production.properties:

```
  logging.config=classpath:logging-spring-production.xml
```

logging-devel.xml (banner displayed)

```
        LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}application.log}"/>
        <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
            ...
        </appender>
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        </root>
    </configuration>
```

logging-production.xml (banner not displayed)

```
        LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}application.log}"/>
        <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
            ...
        </appender>
        <root level="WARN">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        </root>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

During printing a banner Spring Boot uses logger of class `org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication` with `INFO` level.

The simples solution would be to enable `INFO` level for this particular class:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication"
        level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: Changing the logging level for the one class is the best way to go as you say.

An alternative way of doing this for Spring Boot is just via an Environment property, which I'd pass in as a JVM parameter e.g.

-Dlogging.level.org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication=INFO

Comment: Works :) Thank you very much.

Comment: I used Spring Boot 2.6.2 and this did not work for me. I went with ocarlsen's solution and it worked seamlessly.

Answer (score 12):

I had same problem and just set this property in `application.properties`:

```
spring.main.banner-mode=LOG
```

Now it prints to both console and file, with log level INFO.  As long as you have your root log level and appenders set to accept INFO, you will see it.

```
<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</root>
```

Comment: I used Spring Boot 2.6.2 and this solution worked for me and should have been the accepted answer as well. Sasha Shpota's answers, which is apparently the accepted answer and the highest voted one did not work for me.

Comment: the point was root level in production env is WARN and should not be changed, you are changing it...

Answer (score 2):

This is, what I came up with. It wraps around the idea of just replacing the logger in regular implementation.

The problem with using the default log implementation is the way commons-logging is adapted via slf4j bridge.

This is probably one of the ugliest code alive, so hopefully we will see a fix in upcoming spring-boot releases...

Step 1: Register a new application listener

/META-INF/spring.factory

```
 org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=ac.me.appevents.BannerDisplay
```

Step 2: Implement the Application Listener

```
package ac.me.appevents;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Marker;
import org.slf4j.MarkerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.ResourceBanner;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class BannerDisplay implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {
    /**
     * Banner location property key.
     */
    private static final String BANNER_LOCATION_PROPERTY = "banner.location";

    /**
     * Default banner location.
     */
    private static final String BANNER_LOCATION_PROPERTY_VALUE = "banner.txt";

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BannerDisplay.class);

    private static final Marker MRK = MarkerFactory.getMarker("Banner");

    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    private Class<?> deduceMainApplicationClass() {
        try {
            StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = new RuntimeException().getStackTrace();
            for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : stackTrace) {
                if ("main".equals(stackTraceElement.getMethodName())) {
                    return Class.forName(stackTraceElement.getClassName());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            // Swallow and continue
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
        Environment environment = event.getEnvironment();

        String location = environment.getProperty(BANNER_LOCATION_PROPERTY, BANNER_LOCATION_PROPERTY_VALUE);
        ResourceLoader resLoader = getResourceLoader();
        Resource resource = resLoader.getResource(location);
        if (resource.exists()) {
            ResourceBanner banner = new ResourceBanner(resource);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            banner.printBanner(environment, deduceMainApplicationClass(), new PrintStream(baos));
            String charset = environment.getProperty("banner.charset", "UTF-8");
            try {

                LOG.info(MRK, baos.toString(charset));
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                LOG.warn(MRK, "Unsupported banner charset encoding.", e);
            }

        }
    }

    @NotNull
    private ResourceLoader getResourceLoader() {
        if (resourceLoader == null) {
            this.resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader(ClassUtils.getDefaultClassLoader());
        }
        return resourceLoader;
    }

    public void setResourceLoader(final ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I must admit that I have not tested this, but at least it may give you some ideas.

You can remove `spring.main.banner-mode=log` and provide your own wrapper implementation that will use logger instead of provided output stream. Code should look something like this:

```
public class BannerLoggerWrapper implements Banner {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(BannerLoggerWrapper.class);
    private Banner actual;

    public BannerLoggerWrapper(Banner actual) {
        this.actual = actual;
    }

    @Override
    public void printBanner(Environment environment, Class<?> sourceClass, PrintStream out) {
        try {
            logger.info(createStringFromBanner(environment, sourceClass));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            logger.warn("Failed to create String for banner", ex);
        }
    }

    private String createStringFromBanner(Environment environment, Class<?> sourceClass) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        actual.printBanner(environment, sourceClass, new PrintStream(baos));
        String charset = environment.getProperty("banner.charset", "UTF-8");
        return baos.toString(charset);
    }

}
```

You can replace `logger.info` with `logger.warn` in this class or you can create additional config specificaly for this logger:

```
<logger name="your.package.name.BannerLoggerWrapper" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
```

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-banner) you can configure Spring Boot to use your Banner implementation using `SpringApplication.setBanner(…​)`.